# Question Page - Annoying redirection

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When after navigating questions, returns to question list, it automatically returns to page 1 **even** if you found the question from other pages.

---

Ok, here's how the problem in point form if you don't understand a whole bunch of text above.

- Go to any page of the question list(except page **1**)
- Click into any of the questions(in the same tab)
- Click <kbd>Back</kbd> button on your browser
- You are redirected back to page **1** of question list

---

**Can we get redirected back to the page where you clicked the question?** It is so annoying to re-click the page button(s).

Comment: The question list constantly changes, so there is no solid place to get back to except the top of the list.  Consider opening questions in another tab.